# iOS - Can't align UIViews in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have `UIViewController` with `UIScrollView` and two labels and a button inside it:

```
UIView
  -UIScrollView
    -UILabel
    -UILabel
    -UIButton
```

I need to align my `UILabels` and `UIButton` after each other dynamically, as every view can have different size. `UILabels` are okay, but my `UIButton` goes into the middle of my second `UILabel`
Here is my code:

```
self.header.text = event.title;
self.header.numberOfLines = 0;
CGFloat headerHeight = [event.title sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280, 100000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height;
self.header.frame = CGRectMake(19, 20, 280, headerHeight);

CGFloat positionY = 40 + [self.header.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280, 100000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height;

CGFloat descriptionHeight = [event.descr sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280, 100000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height;
self.descr.frame = CGRectMake(19, positionY, 280, descriptionHeight);
self.descr.text = event.descr;
self.descr.numberOfLines = 0; 

positionY =  self.descr.frame.origin.y + self.descr.frame.size.height + 40;

buyButton.frame = CGRectMake(19, positionY, 72, 37);

scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(contentInset, 0, 0, 0);
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, positionY+80)];
```

UIScrollView has flexible height autoresizing mask set in IB.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

If I remove autoresizing mask for my UIScrollView - everything works okay

Comment: Can you upload some images describing the alignment issue you're having?

Comment: Is there a vertical alignment problem here?

Comment: Is `self.descr` the "second label" you refer to?

Comment: Yes, it is. self.header and self.descr are my UILabels and buyButton is my UIButton

Comment: Have you tried printing what `descriptionHeight` is?

Comment: Yeah, it is actual height of my self.descr UILabel. positionY should also be correct - my UIScrollView's content size is set to correct value. Don't know why my UIButton behaves like that

Comment: also if I remove autoresizing mask for my UIScrollView - everything works okay

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18987/discussion-between-dan-f-and-oleg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem resolves itself by changing the autoresizing mask on the scroll view, be sure to check the autoresizing mask on your buttons and labels to make sure they all agree.

Comment: Yes, setting the same autoresizing mask for other views has solved my problem!

Answer (score -2):

Use Count of UISCROLLVIEW subviews and put X axis as

```
  CGRECTMAKE((count-count)*100)+x,y,width,height;
```

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense. `(count-count)` will always be 0